# Correct way to use strcpy() function?

Tags: c, strcpy

What is the correct way to use strcpy() function? I have done it in two ways, and both times the program worked just fine, so I was wondering what's "more correct" way to use it. I want to copy string s2 to s1.

This one:

```
s1=strcpy(s1, s2);
```

or to just write:

```
strcpy(s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second way is correct. The return value of `strcpy()` is always the same as its first argument, so your first version is equivalent to:

```
strcpy(s1, s2);
s1 = s1;
```

That second assignment is obviously pointless. And it would be invalid if `s1` were an array rather than a pointer variable, since you can't assign to arrays.

Comment: So I basically wrote s1=s1 in the first one?

Comment: But you also copied the string to s1.

Comment: Well yeah, that was the intention, so then if I wrote for example s3=strcpy(s1, s2); I would copy s2 to both s1 and s3?

Comment: It's equivalent to `strcpy(s1, s2); s3 = s1;`

Comment: Which would cause a memory leak if `s3` pointed to dynamic memory that you didn't free first.

Answer (score 3):

The function signature is:

```
char* strcpy(char* destination, const char* source);
```

The return value is `destination`. If you want to make use of that value you can, but otherwise you can ignore it.

This is for the case where you want to `return strcpy(x,y)` without having to do an explicit `return x` after the fact.

Note that functions like `strcpy` are intrinsically dangerous because they don't check buffer lengths properly. You should probably use `strcpy_s` or something like it that has an explicit length field so you don't create buffer overflow bugs.

Comment: @Barmar That one, yeah. Fixed.

Comment: Functions like `strcpy()` are only intrinsically dangerous if you don't know how big the source string is or how big the destination array is.  If you know both those, as you should, then `strcpy()` is merely wasteful; you could use `memmove()` — or `memcpy()` — to do the copying.  The trouble is, people often use `strcpy()` where they don't know the sizes in advance, and that can lead to problems, but it is ultimately "careless coding causes crashes" rather than anything wrong with `strcpy()` per se.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The trouble is that crashes are often hints of behaviour that can be exploited, so they're not harmless. That and crashes in general are pretty bad if you're writing C code because you need something fast and reliable. In all honestly GCC and clang should have a `-Wno-legacy-c-functions` that prevents you from using `strcpy` and friends in the first place.

Comment: The bug is in the code calling `strcpy()`. The `strcpy_s()` functions are only available on Microsoft Windows; they're not available on Unix-like platforms, for all they're an optional part of C11 defined in [Annex K](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K). Look at the info in [Do you use the TR 24731 "safe" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/15168) — including a link to the proposal to remove (or at least deprecate before removing) Annex K from the next C standard. And I disagree that the functions are dangerous — it is the programmers who use the functions who are dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to use strcpy() safely, I think this can be useful in case we are using strcpy to copy C string and we know destination buffer size in advance and don't want to use Microsoft specific strcpy_s:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Please give input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char dest[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned int dest_length = (BUFFER_SIZE-1);

    if (strlen(argv[1]) > dest_length)
    {
        printf("Input was too long\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (strlen(strcpy(dest, argv[1])) > dest_length)
    {
        printf("Error in strcpy\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", dest);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After this update now we have much safer strcpy

Comment: Is this a question? If so, you should post it as a new question, not as an answer. The code here shows unsafe use of `strcpy`. User input could be any size, and this code does not check to see if that input will fit into `dest` before calling `strcpy`. This has undefined behavior when the user provides a string longer than 9 characters. 1) choose a reasonable input buffer default for user input, e.g., `char dest[1024];`. 2) check that user input will fit into `dest` first, e.g., `if (strlen(argv[1] < sizeof dest) { /* do strcpy */ } else { /* handle failure */ }`.

Comment: Yes, you are right but it gives me error of stack corrupted in debug may be in release it won't even give error and terminate. I have updated my code. I already said I also trying to use strcpy safely. Thanks.

Comment: The input buffer is made small to demonstrate the usefulness of code.