# C++ strcpy_s throws error when copying to new char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

My goal is to generate a new array with the correct amount of spots and copy an old character array into it.

When using strcpy_s, an exception is thrown. I can not figure out why the exception is being thrown which states that the Buffer is too small. I can not use vectors or strings. How can I fix this using strcpy_s and char arrays?

```
    char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
    int allocated = 4;
    char * reservedString = new char[allocated]();
    strcpy_s(reservedString, allocated, str);
```

EDIT:
Changing my code to add one to the array gives me the same "buffer too small" exception.

```
char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
int allocated = 4;
char * reservedString = new char[allocated+1]();
strcpy_s(reservedString, allocated, str);
```

EDIT 2:
As someone commented str needed to be set to 5 in size and have a null terminator included. Thank you this fixed my problem.

Updated code:

```
    char str[5] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};
    int allocated = 5;
    char * reservedString = new char[allocated]();
    strcpy_s(reservedString, allocated, str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need five characters to store the zero-terminated string `"test"`. Your `str` array is just four characters, with no zero terminator. If you want a zero-terminator, declare it like this:

```
char str[] = "test";
```

Then you need of course

```
int allocated = 5;
```

And after that:

```
char * reservedString = new char[allocated];
strcpy_s(reservedString, allocated, str);
```

Comment: @tevemadar (camelbird?): Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's Hungarian. Tevemadár is a character from an older cartoon series, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_and_the_Magic_Torch (called "Yoo-hoo Bird" in the original)

Answer (score 1):

`char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };` is a 4-byte array in the memory. It is not a string, and it is completely random where a "trailing" zero will occur after these 4 bytes, and an arbitrary amount of other data in between.
However, [`strcpy_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) expects copying a zero-terminated string, just one of the extras it does is checking if the source string will fit into the destination. It will not, that is why you get the error.

> [...] the following errors are detected at runtime and call the currently installed constraint handler function:
>   * src or dest is a null pointer
>   * destsz is zero or greater than RSIZE_MAX
>   * destsz is less or equal strnlen_s(src, destsz); in other words, truncation would occur
>   * overlap would occur between the source and the destination strings

You get the third one, a truncation of the "garbage" bytes would occur.

Answer (score 1):

1. `str` **is not a string**. A string is a sequence of non-NUL characters, terminated by NUL.
2. You should pass the size of the buffer to [`strcpy_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), not the maximum string-size (which is one less).
3. That is, if you should use `strcpy_s()` *at all*. [You shouldn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)

   Use [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), or as you already have the exact size, [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) or [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).
4. As a side-note, zeroing memory just to turn around and overwrite it is a pointless waste.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You are not allocating the proper memory:</strike>

```
char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
```

It allocates 5 bytes, 4 for each character plus the null terminator.---

Do:

```
char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
char * reservedString = new char[5]();
strcpy_s(reservedString, allocated, str);
```

Or:

```
char str[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
char * reservedString = new char[5]();
strcpy(reservedString, str);
```

Comment: It does not allocate five bytes! That is part of the problem: `str` is not null-terminated.

Comment: I tried adding one to the array and it still gave me the "buffer too small" exception. I am worried about using strcpy because it will write memory too far if I have a bug in my code.

Comment: Thank you @TonyK that was my problem!