# memset_s(): What does the standard mean with this piece of text?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In C11, K.3.7.4.1 *The memset_s function*, I found this bit of rather confusing text:

> Unlike `memset`, any call to the `memset_s` function shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine as described in (5.1.2.3). That is, any call to the `memset_s` function shall assume that the memory indicated by `s` and `n` may be accessible in the future and thus must contain the values indicated by `c`.

This implies that `memset` is *not* (necessarily) "evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine". (The chapter referenced is 5.1.2.3 *Program execution*.)

**I fail to understand the leeway the standard gives to `memset` that is explicitly ruled out here for `memset_s`, and what that would mean for an implementor of either function.**

Comment: See "notes" in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

Comment: I would think that the compiler may be allowed to optimize out `memset(p, c,..)` in case it doesn't see any use of the memory pointed by `p` in the future.

Comment: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC06-C.+Beware+of+compiler+optimizations

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Imagine you have read a password:

```
{
    char password[128];

    if (fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin) != 0)
    {
        password[strcspn(password), "\n\r"]) = '\0';
        validate_password(password);
        memset(password, '\0', sizeof(password));
    }
}
```

You've carefully zapped the password so it can't be found accidentally.

Unfortunately, the compiler is allowed to omit that `memset()` call because `password` is not used again.  The rule for [`memset_s()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.4.1) means that the call cannot be omitted; the `password` variable *must* be zeroed, regardless of optimization.

```
memset_s(password, sizeof(password), '\0', sizeof(password));
```

This is one of the few really useful features in [Annex K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions). (We can debate the merits of having to repeat the size.  However, in a more general case, the second size can be a variable, not a constant, and then the first size becomes a runtime protection against the variable being out of control.)

Note that this requirement is placed on the compiler rather than the library.  The `memset_s()` function will behave correctly if it is called, just as `memset()` will behave correctly *if* it is called.  The rule under discussion says that the compiler *must* call `memset_s()`, even though it may be able omit the call to `memset()` because the variable is never used again.

Comment: Wouldn't `memset((volatile void*)password, '\0', sizeof(password));` work around it?

Comment: Not necessarily, no — not least because it isn't clear you can safely pass a volatile pointer to a function that doesn't know it is going to get one.

Comment: Ah right... The function code is already there, so there is no way it can accommodate it..

Comment: @DevSolar: Yes, the requirement is on the compiler to actually generate that call to `memset_s()` even though if the function was `memset()`, it could be omitted.  The library writer merely has to ensure that `memset_s()` does its job.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: IMHO a simple loop `for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof password; i++) { *(volatile char *)(password + i) = 0; }` should do the trick, making `memset_s` a rather useless addition to the C standard.

Comment: @chqrlie I wouldn't call it useless.. You can replace the `memset` with loop too

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Oh... and there I was already hammering those `volatile`s into my `memset_s`... that must be a pain for optimizer maintainers!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler AFAIK `memset_s` can just be a forward to `memset` the only difference is that the compiler is not allowed to optimize it out.

Comment: @chqrlie actually no because of 'AS-IF' if the compiler can detect the buffer isn't read after the writes it's free to remove code that writes up to the last read.

Comment: @Mgetz: more or less.  If you look at the prototype `errno_t memset_s(void *s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n);`, there are a number of differences from `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);`.  And officially, `memset_s()` has to check that `s` is not a null pointer, and so on.  But the grunt work — actually setting the data to the specified byte value — could be handled by `memset_s()` calling `memset()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I realized that after I commented, I do wish glibc etc would implement just that method so people don't have to resort to `volatile` hacks. I could care less about the rest of annex k.

Comment: @Mgetz: Well, the reason I am *working* on Annex K at all is `strtok_s()`, on direct request by downstream... ;-) But yes, most of those functions are a bit clunky. (Including `strtok_s()`, which is worded in a way that *cannot* be fulfilled. :-D )

Comment: @DevSolar AFAIK `strtok_s` and `strtok_r` were macro identical (parameter order changes I believe).

Comment: @DevSolar: Note that Microsoft has its own `strtok_s()` — and the Annex K version is loosely based on the MS version.  The MS `strtok_s()` matches the interface to POSIX `strtok_r()` except in the spelling, but Annex K [`strtok_s()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.3.1) is different from _both_!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OOPS, yeah I got confused because I've used the MS one and macroed before...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I realized. But my lib is strictly ISO 9899 *only*, so I couldn't provide either MS `strtok_s` nor POSIX `strtok_r`... so I implemented ISO `strtok_s` by means of a reserved-namespace worker function, so downstream can either go for ISO `strtok_s` *or* wrap my worker function with a MS `strtok_s` / POSIX `strtok_r`, as per preference. ;-) -- The "impossible" part about ISO `strtok_s` is that I am supposed to bug out if the next token end cannot be found in the next `s1max` characters... but may not access the string with the delimiters if it doesn't. *That* cracked me up. :-D