# issue with strtok to compare two words from a nested results of strtok function

Tags: c

I'm looking for comparing words from an array with words in the dictionary from another array to look for the maximum number of words found

I used strtok since the words in both are delimited with spaces, but it's not working. I need your help please

```
 void chercherScoreMotDansDico(char msgBootforce [], int* 
 maxCorrepondance, char* mot, char* dicoActuel, char* 
 bonResultatBootforce) {
     int i = 0;
     char* motdico = NULL;
     char tmpMsgBootForce [3000] = {0};

     strcpy(tmpMsgBootForce, msgBootforce);

     mot = strtok (tmpMsgBootForce, " ");

     while (mot != NULL) {
          motdico = strtok (dicoActuel, " ");

          while (motdico != NULL) {
              if (strcmp(mot,motdico) == 0)   ++i;
              motdico = strtok (NULL, " ");
          }

          mot = strtok (NULL," ");  
    }

    if (i > *(maxCorrepondance)) {
        *(maxCorrepondance) = i;
        strcat(bonResultatBootforce, msgBootforce);
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Further to the answer, you do a strcpy to be safe with  msgBootforce, you should do the same for dicoActuel.

Comment: Or, since both a space delimited, using a pair of pointers and a simple call to `strchr` is all that is needed to bracket each word. (or use `strcspn/strspn`). Both of which are safe for use on string-literals.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two uses of `strtok()` on two different strings being done at the same time.; `strtok()` has an internal pointer where it stores the address of the current string being processed. If you call `strtok()` with a string and then call `strtok()` with a different string then when you do `strtok(NULL, delim)` it will continue with the last string that was specified.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

> This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the
>   elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be
>   used as the first argument of strtok.  Each call to strtok modifies a
>   static variable: is not thread safe.  Unlike most other tokenizers,
>   the delimiters in strtok can be different for each subsequent token,
>   and can even depend on the contents of the previous tokens.  The
>   strtok_s function differs from the POSIX strtok_r function by guarding
>   against storing outside of the string being tokenized, and by checking
>   runtime constraints.

There is a new version of the `strtok()` function `strtok_s()` which has an additional argument of an address for a pointer variable to use instead of the internal pointer variable that `strtok()` uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `strtok` with two different strings at the same time.

`strtok(string, delim)` stores its position in string internally for future calls to `strtok (NULL, delim)`. It can only remember one at a time. `strtok (tmpMsgBootForce, " ")` says to look through `tmpMsgBootForce` and then `motdico = strtok (dicoActuel, " ")` overwrites that with `dicoActuel`.

---

What to use instead depends on your compiler. The [C standard defines `strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), but that's from the 2011 standard and [has proven to be controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions). [POSIX defines `strtok_r`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html), most Unix compilers will understand that. Finally, [Visual Studio has their own slightly different `strtok_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l?view=vs-2019).

They all work basically the same way. You manually store the position in each string you're iterating through.

Here it is using `strtok_r`. `next_tmpMsgBootforce` and `next_dicoActuel` hold the position for parsing `tmpMsgBootForce` and `dicoActuel` respectively.

```
 char *next_tmpMsgBootforce;
 char *next_dicoActuel;

 strcpy(tmpMsgBootForce, msgBootforce);

 mot = strtok_r(tmpMsgBootForce, " ", &next_tmpMsgBootforce);

 while (mot != NULL) {
      motdico = strtok_r(dicoActuel, " ", &next_dicoActuel);

      while (motdico != NULL) {
          if (strcmp(mot,motdico) == 0)   ++i;
          motdico = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &next_dicoActuel);
      }

      mot = strtok_r(NULL," ", &next_tmpMsgBootforce);  
}
```

Because this is all such a mess, I recommend using a library such as [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.60/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html) to smooth out these incompatibilities and unsafe functions.

---

As a side note, the `strcpy` and `strcat` are not safe. If their destination does not have enough space it will try to write outside its memory bounds. As with `strtok` the situation to do this safely is a mess. There's the non-standard but ubiquitous `strlcpy` and `strlcat`. There's the standard but not ubiquitous [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strcat_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat). Thankfully for once Visual Studio follows the standard.

On POSIX systems you can use `strdup` to duplicate a string. It will handle the memory allocation for you.

```
char *tmpMsgBootForce = strdup(msgBootForce);
```

The caveat is you have to `free` this memory at the end of the function.

Doing a `strcat` safely gets complicated. Let's simplify this by splitting it into two functions. One to do the searching.

```
int theSearching(
    const char *msgBootforce,
    const char *dicoActuel
) {
     int i = 0;
     char *next_tmpMsgBootforce;
     char *next_dicoActuel;

     char *tmpMsgBootForce = strdup(msgBootforce);
     char *tmpDicoActuel = strdup(dicoActuel);

     char *mot = strtok_r(tmpMsgBootForce, " ", &next_tmpMsgBootforce);

     while (mot != NULL) {
          char *motdico = strtok_r(tmpDicoActuel, " ", &next_dicoActuel);

          while (motdico != NULL) {
              if (strcmp(mot,motdico) == 0) {
                  ++i;
              }
              motdico = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &next_dicoActuel);
          }

          mot = strtok_r(NULL," ", &next_tmpMsgBootforce);  
    }

    return i;
}
```

And one to do the appending. This function ensures there's enough space for the concatenation.

```
char *tryAppend( char *dest, const char *src, int *maxCorrepondance, const int numFound ) {
    char *new_dest = dest;

    if (numFound > *maxCorrepondance) {
        *(maxCorrepondance) = numFound;

        // Allocate enough memory for the concatenation.
        // Don't forget space for the null byte.
        new_dest = realloc( dest, strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1 );
        strcat( new_dest, src);
    }

    // Return a pointer to the reallocated memory,
    // or just the old one if no reallocation was necessary.   
    return new_dest;
}
```

Then use them together.

```
int numFound = theSearching(msgBootforce, dicoActuel);
bonResultatBootforce = tryAppend(bonResultatBootforce, msgBootforce, &maxCorrepondance, numFound);
```

Comment: no chance with my compiler:  warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtok_r’; did you mean ‘strtok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: Do you have an idea howto find a word from msgBootforce[] that appears in the array *dicoActuel  without using strtok_s or strtok_r  since it's not working with my compiler?

Comment: @H_B Yes, use Glib's g_strsplit. https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strsplit I highly recommend using GLib, or a similar library, in production C code. It smooths over many issues with C and provides many missing features.

Comment: @H_B What compiler is this? It's odd a compiler would have neither. Are you compiling with any flags that force it to use an old version of C?

Comment: @Schwen gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 -lm -O2

Comment: @H_B Works For Me™ with clang and gcc9 on OS X. Since `strtok_r` is non-standard its availability will vary.