# Can't enter name gets

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char name[30];
};
typedef struct student sv;
int main() {
    int i;
    sv basedata[50] ;
    int totalstudent;
    do
    {
        printf("How many people are there: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &totalstudent);
    } while (totalstudent<0);
    fflush(stdin);
    for ( i = 0; i < totalstudent; i++)
    {
        printf("Person %i name: ", i + 1);
        gets(basedata[i].name);
    }
}
```

output:
How many people are there: 1
Person 1 name:
D:\hello\chuong7\x64\Debug\chuong6.exe (process 26572) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . .

Why I can't enter name for Person 1 name when run my program, my program pass to end and I can't        gets(basedata[i].name). Sorry I'm just study English
[**picture here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIHEw.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq  explains most of the problems in your code.

Comment: Now the real question is what source of learning you are using, because it seems very outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program has many bugs, but the one that is specifically tripping you up is that you are calling `scanf`, which doesn't read input in lines, and then `gets`, which *does*.  After the `scanf`, the carriage return that the user typed after the number is still waiting to be read.  `gets` reads that carriage return instead of the additional input that you are trying to prompt for.  Your call to `fflush(stdin)` does not change this; [what `fflush(stdin)` does, varies from system to system, but it *never* does what people seem to expect it to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin/67906660#67906660).

In addition, [`gets` is dangerous and should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), [`scanf` is broken-as-specified and should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf), and [all of the `_s` functions that Microsoft's compilers like to push on you are unportable and don't fix the problems Microsoft was trying to solve, and (wait for it) should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326623/im-using-linux-compiling-with-gcc-getting-error-warning-implicit-declaratio/60326678#60326678).

Here's what you should do instead:

1. Put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1` at the top of your file (before all the `#include`s) to make MSVC stop giving you bad advice.
2. Use `fgets`, nothing else, to read all lines of input from the user.
3. Use `strtol` to convert the decimal number input to a machine integer.
4. Since you are using a statically allocated array of records, check whether the number input is bigger than the size of the array, before entering the loop.

Best of luck.

Comment: Good answer, this seems completely in line with my answer here: [Which functions from the standard library must (should) be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518) Though today I would probably add all `_s` functions too indeed, after the C11 "bounds checking interface" attempt turned into a fiasco. Also feel free to vote on other answers claiming "deprecated because Microsoft says so" in that same post... :)

Comment: I've also written a post regarding Microsoft myths and `strcpy` specifically here: [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: hello ZWOL, I see some Compiler Warning some function, class member, variable, or typedef that's marked deprecated in visual studio. Can you help me know about that ?, I find a lot function has deprecated but some website which I find information still used.

Comment: @AnNguyen Please ask a new question about that.  Make sure to show the _complete and unedited_ text of all errors.  You may be asked for a "MCVE": see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @zwol how about textcolor(), textbackground() and clrscr;

Comment: @zwol Can you explain to me what is non-static libraries and non-standard function?

Comment: @AnNguyen Please post a new question. Asking unrelated questions in the follow-up comments to an answer is against site policy.