# How to define SCANF to later be the secure function scanf_s()?

Tags: c, scanf

I was given homework where I need to write a C program that first reads in two floating point numbers from the user. I need to use the scanf_s() function for reading in, if your compiler supports the secure functions, using the #if ...#else ...#endif directive.
The assignment sheet says that I have to define SCANF to later be the secure function scanf_s() and add an else part to define SCANF to be the standard function scanf(), but I don’t really understand what that means. Can someone please explain this to me?

I just don't understand the meaning of the problem statement.

Comment: Didn't the teacher teach anything about this?

Comment: `scanf()` and `scanf_s()` are not interchangeable, they take different arguments. You can't use a macro to emulate this.

Comment: Not every compiler implements `scanf_s`. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). To make your application usable across different compilers, you can add preprocessor directives to use the safe one if possible, but to fallback to the less safe one when not.

Comment: @Barmar the different interface between `scanf` and `scanf_s` is a bigger concern than checking for `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`. You're right. They really need to talk to their teaching staff about this.

Comment: @JohnFilleau OTOH, the different interface only applies when reading strings, `%f` is the same.

Comment: @Barmar that sounds like the key to the question. I missed that.

Comment: @Barmar No, at the lecture we only covered data types in c, operators, operator precedence and arrays

Comment: #if defined(_STDC_LIB_EXT1_) || defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ 1
    /* TODO: define SCANF to later be the secure function scanf_s() */
#endif
/* TODO: add an else part to define SCANF to be the standard function scanf() */

Comment: This is what the skeleton of the code looks like and I still don’t understand what is required in the task

Comment: Either `#define SCANF scanf` or `#define SCANF scanf_s` depending on whether it's in `#if` or `#else`.

Comment: [None of the Annex K functions should be used _at all_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326623/im-using-linux-compiling-with-gcc-getting-error-warning-implicit-declaratio/60326678#60326678), as they are unportable and do not actually fix the problems they were intended to fix.  In addition, [scanf itself is broken as specified and should not be used at all either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf?).  This is a bad assignment and you may tell your instructor I said so.

Comment: @zwol Even worse, by far the most widespread implementation of Annex K's (not really) more "secure" functions functions is [incompatible with most others](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations):  "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am painfully aware, yes (isn't that mentioned at the link I gave?)

Comment: @zwol I know you are, but IMO the direct link and that quote needs to be shown to all the pushers of the Annex K functions, especially the details of Microsoft's implementation being non-standard and non-portable.  You never know who might need a retort to someone regurgitating the "`snprintf()` is insecure and Microsoft has banned it!  You must use `snprintf_s()`!!!!" output from some brain-dead "security scanner".

Answer (score 3):

You are being instructed to use [preprocessor directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) to [conditionally](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional) define a [text-replacement macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace) that replaces the token `SCANF` with either `scanf_s` or `scanf`, depending on the availability of the former.

Note that the following is a terrible idea in general, as the variable-arguments accepted by `scanf` and `scanf_s` differ greatly, depending on the format specifier used. Below we only use `%f`, which happens to work the same between both functions. Using `%s`, for example, in the program below would invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

From [some documentation on `scanf_s`:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

> As with all bounds-checked functions, `scanf_s`, `fscanf_s`, and `sscanf_s` are only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant `1` before including `<stdio.h>`.

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#define SCANF scanf_s
#else
#define SCANF scanf
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a, b;

    printf("Enter two floating-point numbers: ");

    if (2 != SCANF("%f%f", &a, &b)) {
        fputs("Could not read input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Got: [%.2f], [%.2f]\n", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1 1` should be `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it became clearer to me

Comment: @IanAbbott Cheers, blindly copied their outline from the comments above.