# How can I add my own messages about an error in assert() in C?

Tags: c, assert, ndebug

I need to get an output with the assertion failing like this:

```
Assertion failed!
Program: C:\...\assert-test.exe
File: C:\...\assert-test.c, Line 21
Expression: denominator != 0.0
```

Can anyone explain to me how to remove the default error message and create my own?
This is how my code looks like:

```
#if defined(_STDC_LIB_EXT1_) || defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ 1
    #define SCANF scanf_s
#else
    #define SCANF scanf
#endif

#ifdef NDEBUG
    #define M_Assert(expr) \
        __M_Assert(buffer, __FILE__, __LINE__, #expr)
#else
    #define M_Assert(expr);
#endif // NDEBUG

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>


int main() {
    double numerator = 0.0, denominator = 0.0;
    printf("--- Quotient of two numbers ---\n\nEnter the nominator: ");
    if (SCANF("%lf", &numerator) < 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n"); return 1;
    }
    printf("denominator: ");
    if(SCANF("%lf", &denominator) < 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n"); return 1;
    }

    M_Assert(denominator != 0);

    printf ("quotient is %f\n", numerator / denominator);
    return
}

void __M_Assert(char *buffer, char *file, int line, char *expr) {
    if(!expr) {
        buffer[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
        std::cerr << "Assssertion failed!\n"
        << "/n"
        << "Programm: \t" << buffer << "\n"
        << "File: \t" << file << ", Line " << line << "\n"
        << "\n"
        << "Expression: \t" << expr << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}
```

So I tried to define NDEBUG to deactivate all assert calls and then define my own assert macro, but nothing works

Comment: You shouldn't name your own functions beginning with `__`, that's reserved to the implementation.

Comment: But the main problem is that you need to put the definition or declaration of `__M_Assert` before `main()`.

Comment: You don't need `;` in the definition of `M_Assert`.

Comment: I don't get why you must use `scanf_s` for floating point input. The point of it is that it supposedly guards against buffer overflow, but you can't use it as a direct replacement with `%s` or `%c`, because of the size argument needed.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I changed this errors, but the same output comes out. And when I  just define NDEBUG. It doesn't work. Is there maybe something else that i could change?

Comment: @WeatherVane It's part of their assignment from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289272/how-to-define-scanf-to-later-be-the-secure-function-scanf-s

Comment: @Barmar I'd seen that. It seems a pretty daft assignment.

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems like they're learning about macros, they used scanf/scanf_s as an example, and defining their own `assert` is another one.

Comment: Are you programming C or C++? `std::cerr` is C++.

Comment: @Barmar I'm programming in C. Thanks. It's my first experience with C. What I should use instead?

Comment: `fprint(stderr, "Assertion failed\n\nProgram:\t%s\nFile:\t%, Line %d\n\nExpression:\t%s\n", buffer, file, line, expr);`

Comment: `buffer[MAX_PATH];` doesn't do anything. If you meant to declare an array it should be `char buffer[MAX_PATH];`. But `buffer` is already declared as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem with your macro is that, once the passed `expr` argument is stringified (with the `#` operator), it is no longer a testable, Boolean expression. Rather, it is a string literal (of type `const char*`) that gets passed to your assert function, and that will never be `NULL` (which is what the `!expr` test is actually checking for, in your code).

You can implement a function that does what you want by adding an extra `int` (or `bool`, if you include the `<stdbool.h>` header) argument and use the **value** of the `expr` argument in the macro that calls the function. It is generally good practice to enclose such arguments in parentheses, when using them in macros.

Note also that you don't need the `buffer` argument, as that can be declared as a local variable (as also mentioned in the comments).

Here is a possible implementation of your assert function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define M_Assert(expr) \
        MyAssert(__FILE__, __LINE__, (expr), #expr)

void MyAssert(const char* file, int line, bool test, const char* expr);

int main(void)
{
    double numerator = 0.0, denominator = 0.0;
    printf("--- Quotient of two numbers ---\n\nEnter the nominator: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &numerator) < 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n"); return 1;
    }
    printf("denominator: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &denominator) < 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n"); return 1;
    }

    M_Assert(denominator != 0);

    printf("quotient is %f\n", numerator / denominator);
    return 0;
}

void MyAssert(const char* file, int line, bool test, const char* expr) {
    if (!test) {
        char buffer[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Assertion failed!\n\n"
            "Program:   \t%s\n"
            "File:      \t%s\n"
            "Line:      \t%d\n"
            "Expression:\t%s\n",
            buffer, file, line, expr);
        abort();
    }
}
```

I have done some 'cleaning up' of the code, also, by addressing the points made in the comments on your question, such as not using an identifier that begins with the double underscore, not using the `scanf_s` function (though your assignment may force you to do this), and using `fprintf` rather than the ***C++*** `std::cerr` output stream.