# How to read and write to a normal text file in C?

Tags: c, file

I wrote this program by seeing a YouTube video.
In that, he used `fopen_s` instead of `fopen` and I have the latest gcc and `g++` compiler installed, but they don't support `fopen_s`. I am running into an error to close the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* file;
    printf("loading file\n");
    file = fopen("testFile.txt", "r+");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR!!!");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("file pointer is loded\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
loading file
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: If `file == NULL` don't call `fclose` since you didn't open anything.

Comment: By the way, I think fopen_s is a Microsoft special.   It's not part of the standard and not available with gcc.

Comment: @Matt: Actually, Microsoft certainly has `fopen_s()`, but it is also an optional part of C11 — see [Annex K.3.5.2.1 The `fopen_s` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1).  I've not checked whether the MS and Annex K specifications are in sync — there are key differences for some of the interfaces in Annex K compared to Microsoft's implementation of the same name.  It is not widely implemented, though.

Comment: Note that since the error message doesn't end with a newline, it doesn't appear before the code crashes.  End messages with newlines in general.  Reporting errors to standard error is also a good idea: `fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!!! Failed to open file %s for read/update\n", "testFile.txt");` (but this also illustrates why you should have a variable name rather than a string literal for the argument to `fopen()` (or `fopen_s()`) — you can use the variable in the error reporting without repeating the string literal.

Comment: You can see the Q&A [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) for more information about problems with TR 24731 and Annex K compared with Microsoft.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler states above, error messages *must* go to stderr.  But you must also include the reason for the failure (eg, either with `perror`, or `strerror`, or some other mechanism.).  For example:   `if( ( file = fopen("testFile.txt", "r+")) == NULL ) { perror("testFile.txt"); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as described in the comments by Retired Ninja, you shouldn't close the file in the case `file = NULL` because in that case nothing was opened. C will try to call the close function on a NULL pointer which will result in a seg fault.

To find out the reason, substitute your `printf("ERROR!!");` for `perror("error \n");`, which will give you the reason for the file not being succesfully opened.

What I suspect, in your case, is that you should give the directory of the file when calling fopen.