# C++: location of localtime_s in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, time, localtime

Following the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and compiling with `gcc-11.2.0` like so

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -O3 -flto -fPIC ...
```

I am not able to use `localtime_s` in my program:

```cpp
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <time.h>

using SystemClock = std::chrono::system_clock;
const auto in_time_t = SystemClock::to_time_t(SystemClock::now());

struct tm buf; localtime_s(&in_time_t, &buf);
// error: there are no arguments to ‘localtime_s’ that depend on a template parameter, 
//        so a declaration of ‘localtime_s’ must be available [-fpermissive]

struct tm buf; std::localtime_s(&in_time_t, &buf);
// error: ‘localtime_s’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘localtime’?
```

Am I doing something wrong or `localtime_s` is not available in GCC? Or it is only available for pure C programs (for example, compiled with `gcc -std=c11`)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is available in `<time.h>` but not `<ctime>`

Comment: It's maybe worth a note to add to the answers you've gotten that neither `localtime_r` nor `localtime_s` are in the `std` namespace. These C functions are in the global namespace. In Linux for example, you can `#include <ctime>` and use `std::localtime` _and_ `localtime_r` - but not `std::localtime_r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the functions specified in the standard ending with `_s` were originally developed by Microsoft as alternates to functions ending in `_r`.

On Linux systems, `localtime_s` is not defined but `localtime_r` is, and has the same parameters/return type, so use that instead.

Comment: Note that Microsoft's `localtime_s()` has a very different interface from `localtime_r()` — see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As noted elsewhere, the `_s` functions were originally developed by Microsoft.  They are incorporated into C11 as normative but optional Annex K.

Unfortunately, there are differences between what the standard specifies and what Microsoft implemented.

Microsoft implemented [`localtime_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s) with the interface:

```c
errno_t localtime_s(
   struct tm* const tmDest,
   time_t const* const sourceTime
);
```

Standard C11 requires [`localtime_s()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.8.2.4):

```c
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <time.h>
struct tm *localtime_s(const time_t * restrict timer,
       struct tm * restrict result);
```

And POSIX defines [`localtime_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime_r.html):

```c
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *restrict timer,
       struct tm *restrict result);
```

As you can see, the standard C and the Microsoft functions `localtime_r()` have very different interfaces — the arguments are in the reverse order and the return type is different.  By contrast, the difference between the Standard C and POSIX functions is just the name.

This is a fairly general problem with the `_s` functions.  The interface standardized by ISO differs from the interface standardized by Microsoft, often for good reasons.  You can find other information about the problems with `_s` functions in the Q&A [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions).  It has numerous references to other examples of differences between the Standard C and Microsoft variations of the `_s` (safe) functions, and also to a discussion document suggesting that the safe functions are not all that helpful.