# Why does this sprintf_s throw an exception?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, tr24731

```
char filePrefix[] = "test";
char fileName[100]; fileName[0] = 0;
sprintf_s(fileName, "%s", filePrefix);
```

I can't figure out why there's an exception writing into fileName in the sprintf_s

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF885E3F3A9 (ucrtbased.dll) in foo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000008331F00000.
```

Comment: Read the documentation. You're missing  the `buffersize` argument after `fileName`.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use this Microsoft-specific function. There's a standard `snprintf()` that's similar.

Comment: @Barmar int sprintf( char          *buffer, const char          *format, ... );

Comment: That's `sprintf`, not `sprintf_s`.

Comment: @Barmar Dang. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar: Is `sprintf_s` still Microsoft-specific? According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it appears to be in C11.

Comment: @FredLarson It is part of the *optional* implementation, detailed in Annex K of the specification.

Comment: @Oka: Very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @FredLarson Further reading on the annex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions

Comment: @nicomp Did your compiler not warn you about this error?  It could/should have.  C used to have a (pretty well-deserved) reputation for being frustrating and difficult to learn, but if everybody could only use modern compilers with decent warnings, things wouldn't be nearly so bad.

Comment: @Steve The 11th commandment: Heed thy warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170), the second argument to `sprintf_s` should be the size of the destination buffer.

```
char filePrefix[] = "test";
char fileName[100];
fileName[0] = 0;
sprintf_s(fileName, sizeof fileName, "%s", filePrefix);
```