# Shifting characters in string

Tags: arrays, c, string, character-encoding

Hi I want to write a program which takes a string and a number as input and then shifts the elements of string by given number, and also the string is always capital letters and  the output should only be capital letters too
example 1 : -1 , "AB CD"
output  1 : "ZA BC"
example 2 : +3 , "ABC"
output  2 : "DEF"
I have written this code but if there is a space in my string , the program doesnt work properly
for example : -1 "AA AA"
the output is : "ZZ" But i was expecting "ZZ ZZ"

```
int main()
{
    char str[100] = {NULL},y;
    int n,x,i=0;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    scanf_s("%s", str);
    while (str[i] != NULL) {
        x = str[i];
        if (x + n >= 65 && x + n <= 90) {
            y = x + n;
            str[i] = y;
        }
        else if (x + n < 65) {
            while (x + n < 65) {
                x += 26;
            }
            y = x + n;
            str[i] = y;
        }
        else if (x + n > 90) {
            while (x + n > 90) {
                x -= 26;
            }
            y = x + n;
            str[i] = y;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show what you have tried, and ask a question about it.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing this? What have you done so far, what exactly is your problem? Please edit your question to show your current effort.

Comment: @agent007, Save time.  Enable all warnings to see `scanf_s("%s", str);` has troubles.

Answer (score 1):

After reading non-whitespace, the `scanf` specifier `%s` stops when it encounters whitespace.

Instead of `"%s"`, use `" %99[^\n]"` to:

- read and ignore leading whitespace, then
- read up to 99 characters, or until a newline character is encountered.

Reading at most `99` characters is important, as you must leave room in your buffer for the null-terminating byte, and not limiting the amount of data read can easily lead to buffer overflows.

The return value of `scanf_s` should be checked to ensure the expected *number of conversions* took place, before any data is used.

```
if (1 != scanf_s("%d", &n))
    /* error! */;
```

Note that [`scanf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) requires a secondary argument when using `%s` or `%[`, which is the size of the buffer

```
char buf[10];
if (1 != scanf_s("%9s", buf, (rsize_t) sizeof buf))
    /* error! */;
```

which is supposed to be of type [`rsize_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error). If you are using the MSVC [versions of these functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170), this type is `unsigned`.

---

Due to the [pitfalls](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) involved with using `scanf` properly, and the [portability issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) of `scanf_s`, consider instead using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read *lines* of input (and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to parse an integer).

For clarity, consider using character constants like `'A'` and `'Z'`, instead of integer constants like `65` and `90`.

As is, your current code does not account for non-alphabetic characters, and will shift those. Consider the use of [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) or [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) to filter the application of the shift.

Note `NULL` is usually considered a [pointer value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL). Use `'\0'`, or just `0`, to represent the null-terminating byte.