# ERROR: modpost "memset_s" [xxx/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined

Tags: c, linux-kernel

My Linux kernal version change from 4.18 to 5.14 recently. When I compile one of my ko, I got some errors in Makefile maybe. It told me that `ERROR: modpost "memset_s" [xxx/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined!`.
If I can add EXPORT_SYMBOL() in the source file, how can I solve this problem

If I can't add EXPORT_SYMBOL() in the source code, how can I solve this problem

Comment: Plus, I wonder if can solve the problem by only editing the Makefile

Comment: Add `-Dmemset_s(a,b,c,d)=memset(a,c,d)` to the compile flags in the Makefile?

Comment: The problem must be in your module source. Why is it calling `memset_s`?

Comment: Are you defining `memset_s` in one of your kernel modules and trying to export it to another of your kernel modules?

Answer (score 2):

For most practical purposes, [`memset_s()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.4.1) and the other `_s` "safe" functions are only implemented by Microsoft on Windows.  Therefore, `memset_s()` almost certainly won't work in the Linux kernel.  (Having said that, it is intriguing that it used to work.)

There is considerable resistance to implementing the functions outside of Microsoft. However, C23 adds the function `memset_explicit()`, which is supposed to guarantee that the memory is set — the compiler is not supposed to optimize it out.  That is valuable for zapping passwords in memory, for example.  This property was also required by the specification of `memset_s()`.

See also [Do you use the TR-24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/15168) for considerable information about the [Annex K](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K) functions.

Answer (score 0):

`memset_s` and friends are available through the [safec library](https://rurban.github.io/safeclib/doc/safec-3.7.0/index.html).   Note that there are special instructions halfway down this page on using this with Linux kernel modules.